# Node.JS Download file to server following redirects

Tags: node.js, http, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to download Facebook profile pictures using Node.JS, but I'm having problems because Facebook does a redirect.

**URL:** https://graph.facebook.com/userId/picture?type=large

My download function:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('follow-redirects').https;

var download = function(uri, filename) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var data = "";
    https.get(uri, function(response) {
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
            data += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            fs.writeFile(filename, data, 'binary', function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err.message);
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
            })
        });

    }).on('error', function(err) {
        fs.unlink(filename);
        deferred.reject(err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

I only get one chunk, so the resulting file is corrupted.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

function download(uri, filename) {
    var protocol = url.parse(uri).protocol.slice(0, -1);
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var onError = function (e) {
        fs.unlink(filename);
        deferred.reject(e);
    }
    require(protocol).get(uri, function(response) {
        if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
            var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
            fileStream.on('error', onError);
            fileStream.on('close', deferred.resolve);
            response.pipe(fileStream);
        } else if (response.headers.location) {
            deferred.resolve(download(response.headers.location, filename));
        } else {
            deferred.reject(new Error(response.statusCode + ' ' + response.statusMessage));
        }
    }).on('error', onError);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```